# i have been trying to retrive data from two different tables in my database using eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

[employee table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nBGU.png) i have a fully running [allLeave table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmdIj.png) [edited allLeave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQa5M.png)project but i want to merge a leave management system with it so i want to retrieve the full name in the table "employee" and i also want to retrieve some data from a table "allLeave".

in my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\leaveType;
use App\allLeave;
use App\leaveDepartment;

class LeavesController extends Controller
{
    public function getAllLeave()
    {
        $data = App\allLeave::find(1)->full_name;
        return view('leave/allLeave',["data"=>$data]);
    }
}
```

in my employee model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Class Personnel
 * @package App
 */
class Employee extends Audit
{
    public function leave()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\allLeave');
    }
}
```

in my allLeave model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class allLeave extends Model
{
    public function empolyees()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Employee');
    }
}
```

Comment: and am trying to use @foreach($employee as $employee) in the blade file

Comment: @lagbox thanks for the edit... am actually new here thats why

Comment: Please post full models to get better understanding

Comment: @farooq i have alot of thing in the model its just the newly inserted code thats not working

Comment: @farooq please help me look into it

Comment: @farooq Please have uploaded the headers of the models

Comment: no worries, just making the code easier for everyone to read ..... i assume `function empolyees` is a typo?

Comment: @lagbox am actually progressing as the other has posed some things for the to follow but now am getting this error Trying to get property 'employee' of non-object (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/al-halal/resources/views/leave/allLeave.blade.php)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done (*Based on code you have shared*). You should be doing something like

```
$allLeave = App\allLeave::find(1);

# one-to-many, employees is a collection. ["emp_01_full_name", ....]
$data = $allLeave->employees->pluck('full_name')->values();
```

#### Update

```
/* Your view will have an array like
 $data = [
    ['leave_type' => 'casual', 'leave_days' => 2, 'full_name' => 'farooq']
    ...
 ]
*/
$data = $allLeave->pluck(['leave_type', 'leave_days', 'employees.full_name'])->values();
```

#### How to use it in your view

```
return view('leave/allLeave', compact(['data']));

OR

return view('leave/allLeave', ['data' => $data]);
```

Comment: Please how do i fetch the data in the table i want to use it

Comment: `$data` will have an array of employee full_name. Please mention the field you want from allLeave & employees.

Comment: i want to collect the leave type and leave days from the allLeave. i want to collect the full name from the employee table.